# "ARM7 - how to read port pin in LPC2368?"

Tags: embedded, gpio, lpc, embedded-control

I'm using LPC2368 wherein I have got to read the pin status if it is pressed or not?
In arm7 I have connected that pin(which I have to monitor) to EINT2. I'm confused with pinsel section & how do i come to know if the key is pressed or not?
I have used FIO2PIN and stored it in some variable

```
x = FIO2PIN;
```

then checked condition:

```
if(x == ((IN_Tamper >> 12) & 0X1) == 1)
```

wherein IN_Tamper is 0X1000;

Comment: That boolean logic seem a bit weird.  Read the FIOPIN into X and just AND it with the mask value for the EINT2 pin.  The result will be 0 or not 0, depending on pin state.  Also, like @TurboJ says, more stuff - what do you do with the PINSEL registers?

Comment: Note that your question is very specific to the LPC2xxx MCU.  ARM7 defines only the processor core and does not include GPIO or interrupt controller (or any peripherals) - the answer for ARM7 devices from other vendors will be different - you should perhaps change the title of the question.

Comment: The whole point of `IN_Tamper` is so that you don't need to 'know' that it is bit 12 and avoid a 'magic number'.  Right shifting it by 12 rather misses the point.  You should therefore test `(x & IN_Tamper) != 0`

Comment: Having connected the switch to EINT2 it would perhaps make sense to use an interrupt handler - otherwise EINT2 is irrelevant and its just a GPIO issue.  You have not actually stated what happens or whether this code works or not.

Comment: This is probably relevant: http://www.keil.com/forum/17762/, and this: http://read.pudn.com/downloads65/sourcecode/embed/231658/LPC23xx_24xxSampleSoftware.beta1/Keil/EXTINT/extint.c__.htm

Comment: Also http://www.lpcware.com/content/nxpfile/sample-code-bundle-lpc23xxlpc24xx-peripherals-using-keils-%CE%BCvision

Comment: Typically to get a GPIO to work on a device like this, you have to have powered, clocked, and direction configured the GPIO port.  Then you have to define a pointer to a volatile data type, often of an explicitly allowed width (it may be mandatory to access it as 16 bit, or as 32 bit depending on the hardware).  There's a lot to get wrong, so if you can find manufacturer example code which does the configuration, and a header file with pointer defines for the ports to start from that is going to be a shorter path than working out the requirements from the data sheet.

Comment: I did it my self as folloing code

Comment: DIR_IN_TAMPER;
 x = FIO2PIN & TAMPER_PIN;
 x = FIO2PIN & TAMPER_PIN;
 if((x & (1<<12) !=0))
  BUZZER_ON
 else
  BUZZER_OFF

wherein IN_TAMPER = 0x00001000;

Comment: used it twice b'z I wanted to check what if I don't press key will value of x changes??

so used it twice..

thank you then too!!

Comment: @ Clifford ya I have used EINT0 as GPIO.
but before I was committing mistake of using it as interrupt pin.
my code is working perfectly.
thank you!!